# A simple inequality in about integer part of numbers?

Tags: calculus, inequality

*This question follows [`A simple inequality in calculus?`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436712/a-simple-inequality-in-calculus).*

I have to solve this inequality in about $s$:

$$\left(\left[\dfrac{r}{s}\right] + 1 \right)  s \le 1,$$ 
where   $ 0 < s < 1 $ and also  $ 0 < r < 1 $.

That inequality is in about `Computer Programming` problem.$r$ is an input that user enter it when App is run.Also $s$ is another user input,but user must input it before $r$ and I have to find which $s$ in the range $\left(0,1\right)$ satisfies the inequality for all $r$.So if user choose a number as $s$ out of that range,I can notice him and he can try again.

I guess that $s$ must be in this range: $\left(0,\dfrac{1}{2}\right]$.But I do not know if my guess is true. If so, how I can prove it?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple inequality in calculus?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436712/a-simple-inequality-in-calculus)

Comment: @nrpeterson Please pay attention,inequality is different.It has 2 variables and "less than or equal" instead of "less than" sign.

Comment: If $r$ is close to 1, then $[r/s]$ will be almost $1/s$, and the product will be almost $1+s$. Some experimentation may convince you it's not so easy to find an $s$ that works for all $r$.

Comment: The reasoning in that earlier problem may still come in handy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your times.I try to use it.Although it is obvious that s can be 0.5 .

Comment: Yes, after you changed the $\lt$ to $\le$, $s=1/2$ works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $s$ is not the reciprocal of an integer (i.e. $\frac1s\notin\mathbb N$), then for $r$ sufficiently close to $1$, we have $$\left\lfloor \frac rs\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac 1s\right\rfloor$$
and
$$ \left(\left\lfloor \frac rs\right\rfloor+1\right)s=\left(\left\lfloor \frac 1s\right\rfloor+1\right)s>\left(\frac1s-1+1\right)s=1.$$
On the other hand, if $s=\frac1n$ with $n\in\mathbb N$ (and of course $n\ge2$), then $\frac rs<n$, hence 
$$\left\lfloor \frac rs\right\rfloor\le n-1$$
and 
$$ \left(\left\lfloor \frac rs\right\rfloor+1\right)s\le\left(n-1+1\right)s=1.$$

So $s$ has the desired property iff it is the reciprocal of a natural number.